# Multiplying a column in a Spark dataframe by a constant value

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I am having an issue creating a new column in my Spark dataframe. I'm attemping to create a new column using withColumn() as follows:

```
.withColumn('%_diff_from_avg', 
     ((col('aggregate_sales') - col('avg_sales')) / col('avg_sales') * 100))
```

This results in some values calculated correctly, but most of the values in my resultant table are null. I don't understand why.

Interestingly, when I drop the '* 100' from the calculation, all my values are populated correctly - i.e. no nulls. For example:

```
.withColumn('%_diff_from_avg', 
    ((col('aggregate_sales') - col('avg_sales')) / col('avg_sales')))
```

seems to work.

So it seems that the multiplication by 100 is causing the issue.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I tried same example with scala and its looks fine for me, I think there is something wrong with your data could you check once

Comment: @SandeepPurohit I am facing the same issue in scala. Can you tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: @nikitap Can you please explain the issue in detail?

Comment: The issue for me had been that some Decimal type values were exceeding the maximum allowable length for a Decimal type after being multiplied by 100, and therefore were being converted to nulls. Check the lengths / types of your fields to make sure that you are using the correct types for the values you are trying to store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happened with me too. It could be some issue with the types of data of your columns. Try this:

```
.withColumn('%_diff_from_avg', 
     ((col('aggregate_sales') - col('avg_sales')) / col('avg_sales') * 100.0))
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap the constant number with `lit()`

```
.withColumn('%_diff_from_avg', 
     ((col('aggregate_sales') - col('avg_sales')) / col('avg_sales') * lit(100)))
```

Comment: tested, it's ok.